# Spring Security LDAP Load Roles from LDAP

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-ldap

Using Spring Security LDAP and its authenticating fine, but now I need to load the userLevel attribute from the LDAP entry to determine what level a user is.

My Spring Security configuration looks like this

```
@Profile(value = {"sit", "uat", "prod"})
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    protected Environment environment;

    public SecurityConfig() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.ldapAuthentication()
                .userSearchBase("dc=fantasycompany,dc=com")
                .userDnPatterns("cn={0},ou=users,ou=somedepartment,o=departments,c=US,dc=fantasycompany,dc=com")
                .contextSource()
                    .url("ldaps://someserver:636")
                    .managerDn("cn=someone,cn=users,dc=fantasycompany,dc=com")
                    .managerPassword("somethingsomething");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        /**httpSecurity.authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/perform_login")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/",true)
                    .failureUrl("/login.html?error=true");*/

        httpSecurity
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login*").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/css/*").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/",true)
                .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID");
    }
}
```

How am I able to get Spring to load the userLevel property from the LDAP entry into the ROLES?

Answer (score 0):

You either need a custom LdapAuthoritiesPopulator which reads an attribute (e.g. 'memberOf' when AD is used or 'isMemberOf' when using OpenDJ) to extract the 'roles'.

The ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider does this without using an LdapAuthoritiesPopulator.